# PageMenu selected tab going beyond left margin

Tags: ios

I applied a PageMenu, You can check it on https://github.com/PageMenu/PageMenu. I'm facing problem after selecting some tabs , half of its title is going beyond left margin like shown in the image. What I'm looking for is getting complete title on left without getting truncated or on centre.[image: Selected tab going on left**strong text**]